# Why layout is different in graphical layout and AVD , where both are working on android 2.2 API 8

Tags: android, layout, android-virtual-device

I am making one layout but when i see that layout in graphical layout and in AVD manager, AVD manager displays somewhat different layout than graphical layout. Please help me to fix this problem.

look at below..

[enter link description here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66060625/Untitled.png)

Comment: I am not able to put images. So i can exactly show that what problem is...it needs reputation..!!

Comment: Let me ask my cristal balls.

Comment: you could paste it in tinypic.com or something and paste link here. Think dude..

Comment: i did it thanx....but please solve my main problem...m stuck there

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley I cannot comment on your post.. but could you please upload your .xml file? Maybe you built your layout on a "screen" with a resolution different from the one of AVD VM or you are using a relative layout. Just post the .xml

Try changing your xml layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#54616d"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dial Number"
        android:textColor="#f7edb3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator" 
        android:background="#f7edb3" 
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:text="#"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dial"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#c79c00"
                android:text="Dial" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: first link is the image of my problem and second link is xml of that graphical lauout of that dialler